# Verification: If $\int_a^bf(x)dx=0$ then there is $x_0\in [a,b]$ for which $f(x_0)=0$

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-verification

Old exam question: Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R} : a<b$ and let $f$ be a continuous function,  $[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

Show that if 
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx=0$$
then there is $x_0\in [a,b]$ such that $f(x_0)=0$

Hint: $f$ can only have a sign, if $f$ has no roots.

My approach:$f$ is continuous so by the fundamental theorem there is $F$ such that
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx = F(b)-F(a)=0$$ and $F'=f$

Then by the intermediate value theorem for derivatives we have 
$$0=\frac{F(b)-F(a)}{b-a}=F'(\zeta)=f(\zeta)$$
for some $\zeta\in(a,b)$

Now for my question: why the hint? I'm afraid I may have misunderstood the question as I don't even know how to use the hint.

Comment: @MatthewDaly Thanks, edited

Comment: By the hint it suffices to consider $f>0$ or $f<0$ everywhere, which is a lot easier.

Comment: Your solution is OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $a<b$. Proof suggested by the hint: If $f$ has no zeros then it has the same sign throughout the interval. Let us say $f(x) >0$ for all $x$. Since $f$ is continuous it attains its minimum value $m$ so $m >0$. This gives $\int_a^{b}f(x)dx >m(b-a)$ so the integral cannot be $0$.

Comment: Advantage with this proof: no derivatives used.

Comment: Thank you very much, sir, very elegant! For peace of mind: was mine wrong or just lengthy?

Comment: Nothing wrong at all with your proof.